# How to start at certain number in array R?

Tags: r

If I have this array:

```
   vector1 <- c(5,9,3)
   vector2 <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
   result <- array(c(vector1,vector2,vector1,vector2,vector1,vector2,vector1,vector2,vector1,vector2,vector1,vector2),dim = c(3,3,12))
   str(result)
  num [1:3, 1:3, 1:12] 5 9 3 10 11 12 13 14 15 5 ...
```

What I need is to start from [,,4] and count 3 so I will have

```
 [,,4] [,,5] [,,6] and then compute the mean for them 
 [,,7] [,,8] [,,9] and then compute the mean for them
 [,,10] [,,11] [,,12] and then compute the mean for them
```

Comment: You're wanting something like `mean(result[,,4:6])`, which returns a single number?

Comment: No I want the mean for each three and the output should be matrix not one value.

Comment: So you want a 3x3 matrix where the top left element is the mean of `[,,4]`, the top right is the mean of `[,,6]` and so on?

Comment: this sounds like a job for `apply` --- check out the help page for some examples with arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option.  Subset the 'result' with the indices along the third dimension, `split` the sequence of third dimension with a grouping variable created with `gl`, loop through the index, subset the `array` elements based on index, `Reduce` by getting the `sum` of corresponding elements and divide by 3 to get the `mean`

```
s1 <- result[,, 4:12]
i1 <- seq(dim(s1)[3])
out <- lapply(split(i1, as.integer(gl(length(i1), 3, length(i1)))),
     function(i) Reduce(`+`, lapply(i, function(i2) s1[,, i2]))/3)
```

If we want as `array` output

```
array(unlist(out), c(3, 3, 3))
```

---

Or `melt` it to 'long' format with the indices, then create the grouping varioable, `summarise` to get the `mean`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
melt(result[, , 4:12]) %>%
   group_by(Var1, Var2, grp = ((Var3-1) %/% 3 ) + 1) %>%
   summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
   split(.$grp) %>% 
   map(~ .x %>% 
            select(-grp) %>% 
            spread(Var2, value) %>% 
            tibble::column_to_rownames('Var1')) %>% 
   unlist %>% 
   array(c(3, 3, 3))
```

Comment: Thanks. the output is a list?

Comment: @temor It can be converted to `array`, by `array(unlist(out), c(3, 3, 3))`

Comment: Thanks.Yes it works final question how to compute the mean of the output "out" and get one final matrix?

Comment: @temor `Reduce("+", out)/3`